# Shiny/R: Formatting graph date from character date

Tags: r, date, graph, shiny

I have spent hours on this and I am a new user. I've been to many websites and tried different things.   I can not seem to get the graph to show dates in a YYYY-MM format on the x axis.  The date starts out being character, which seems to work for the date range inputs. But the graph date is either showing as a long number or as Mar-01, Apr-01, etc.  I'd rather see 2017-Feb, 2017-Mar, 2017-Apr, 2017-May. IF they would not sort appropriately like this I would need 2017-02, 2017-03, etc. (or even 201702 - just some year then month format).  My app has several dynamic UI, which are working.  What I'm showing is a simple version but I left the date range pick in just in case that is relevant.

```
   library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)

data_source_end = c("2/28/2017","3/31/2017", "4/30/2017", "5/31/2017")

mean_score = c(1.5, 2.5 , 3.5, -.5)

df <- data.frame(data_source_end, mean_score)
df$data_source_char <- as.character(df$data_source_end)
df$data_source_mdy <- as.Date(mdy(df$data_source_char),"%Y-%m-%d")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("dates","DateRange",
                               start = min(df$data_source_char),
                               end = max(df$data_source_char))
      ),

    mainPanel( 
      plotOutput("plot2")
  )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$DateRange <- renderText({
    #i have  validate messages here 
  })

  fildata <- reactive({
    fildata  <-  df
    filtered2 <- fildata %>%
      select(data_source_mdy, mean_score ) %>%
      dplyr::arrange(data_source_mdy)
    return(filtered2)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    x <-fildata()$data_source_mdy
    y <-  fildata()$mean_score 
    plot(x, y, xlim=c(input$dates[1],input$dates[2] )
    )
  })

}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `axis.Date(side = 1, at = x, format = "%Y-%m")` to get the date format where format parameter `%Y-%m` specifies `YYYY-MM` format.

Your `output$plot2` would look something like this:

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      x <-fildata()$data_source_mdy
      y <-  fildata()$mean_score 
      plot(x, y, xlim=c(input$dates[1],input$dates[2]), xaxt = "n")
      axis.Date(side = 1, at = x, format = "%Y-%m")
    })
```